# What can I use to capture every command I run in bash (a-la history)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I know history will capture commands that I run, but it is shell specific. I work with multiple shells and multiple hosts and would like to write a small script which, after every command I run, dumps that command to some file along with the host name. This way, i can implement my own history command which reads from that file, and can take a host as an argument which would be handy for me. I'm not sure how to get the first part though..i.e., get every shell command I type to trigger a "dump that command into a file" part. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know whether is possible but maybe you could use **inotify** and **inotify-tools** and monitor the directories with executable files and write a log file whenever one of these files gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, the [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables) environment variable contains a command that will be executed before the `PS1` prompt is displayed. So yours could be something like `history | tail -n1 | perl -npe 's/^\s+\d+\s+//' | yourcommand HOST`

Comment: I followed this idea but I keep getting the history file line numbers and I'm not sure why..i have something like: 

    PROMPT_COMMAND='history | tail -n1 | perl -npe 's/^\s+\d+\s+//' '
    export PROMPT_COMMAND

if i run that command manually i don't get the line number but when it gets done by PROMPT_COMMAND it does happen..i.e:

    host_69:/home/palace/history $ history | tail -n1 | perl  -npe    's/^\s+\d+\s+//'
    history | tail -n1 | perl -npe 's/^\s+\d+\s+//'
     1106  history | tail -n1 | perl -npe 's/^\s+\d+\s+//'

Comment: Actually, try the `fc` command instead. It takes options to not print the line numbers. To get the most recent command you can do `$(fc -lnr | head -n1)` although you will get a bunch of whitespace at the start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

The [`script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) utility should solve your problem. It records everything you type and all that is printed on the terminal in a file (even including terminal control codes, so if you `cat` that file on the console, you even reproduce the original text colors).